# pyinstaller not copying data file to ./dist dir

Tags: pyinstaller

i have the following pyinstaller spec file

i have a translation file in ./translate/nl_NL.qm

from the line datas=[ ('translate/nl_NL.qm', 'translate' )], i expect that file to be copied to ./dist/translate/nl_NL.qm.

What am i doing wrong?

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['inifileedit.py'],
             pathex=['/home/rob/socktest/qt5projects/inifileedit'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[ ('translate/nl_NL.qm', 'translate' )],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='inifileedit',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

Comment: No, by doing that you tell pyinstaller to embed translate/nl_NL.qm in the exe and make it accessible as translate/nl_NL.qm by the exe.

Comment: Thanks for the note. so how can i then access that file.  if i do self.translator.load("translate/nl_NL.qm") the file  is not found.

Comment: Do you want to embed the nl_NL.qm file within your exe or keep in separately ? If teh answer is "embed" just have a look a https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file (specialy second code snippet). If not just copy it manualy to dist/translate and remove the information in `datas`

Comment: thanks, i will "read the docs"

Answer (score 0):

Eric Mathieu soved my problem

it tuns out pyinstaller  unpacks the data in a different place than i thought

this code works both in the interpreter and pyinstaller

```
# get path to where pyinstaller will unpack ./translate
# if not packed by pyinstaller returns location of .py file
bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))

if (Lang == "Eng"):
    _tr = "translate/en_US.qm"  
if (Lang == "Dut"):
    _tr = "translate/nl_NL.qm"

self.translator.load(path.join(bundle_dir, _tr))
```